Gauge Theory : Mathematics + Physics
I'm interested in learning mathematical gauge theory, particularly its applications in physics, focusing on (topological) quantum field theory with an emphasis on condensed matter.
I'm looking for mathematically precise references that are rich in physical examples. Do you know of any books, notes, or papers that fit this description? I'm open to consulting multiple sources but would like to start with the most comprehensive set available.

The first references that come to my mind are Mathematical Gauge Theory by Hamilton and the two volumes called Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields by Naber. Naber book comes with more worked out examples I think. Keep in mind that I am by no means an expert and I know nothing about the underlying Physics (these are just the books I'm using for a course at uni). P.S. Michor's books are also great, but they are heavily on the differential geometry side of the story.
